# How to iterate over a json dictionary in Svelte

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Svelte, the #each construct can be used to iterate over an array-like object. If one has a JSON dictionary object instead, does Svelte provide a way to iterate over the JSON dictionary in order to populate a dropdown menu? My data is the result of an API call and looks like:

```js
const obj = { foo: "bar", batz: "boink" }
```

Comment: Not sure about svelte, but the js Object api gives you ways to turn objects into lists. Object.keys, Object.values, and Object.entries.

Comment: Actually `{ foo: "bar", batz: "boink" }` it's not a JSON it's just an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first convert your object to an array with the infos (keys/values/boths) you would like to display.
This array is then iterable with an #each loop.
See this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f1a9112c7ba749b6910da74a202bca92?version=3.44.0)

```html
<script>
const obj = { foo: "bar", batz: "boink" }

let keys = Object.keys(obj)  // ["foo", "batz"]
let values = Object.values(obj)  // ["bar", "boink"]
let entries = Object.entries(obj)  // [["foo", "bar"], ["batz", "boink"]]

</script>

{#each entries as [key, value]}
    <div>
    {key} - {value} 
    </div>  
{/each}
```

Comment: Note that the script tags are not necessary. You can do it in line as well:
{ #each Object.entries(obj) as [key, value] }